# Can boost::asio::yield_context set a std::error_code instead of boost::system::error_code?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio, coroutine

I'm writing a C++11 networking library that uses Boost.Asio under the hood. I want to expose an API that allows users to use stackful coroutines.

`boost::asio::yield_context` overloads the `[]` operator so that an asynchronous operation may set an error code instead of throwing an exception. For example:

```
std::size_t n = my_socket.async_read_some(buffer, yield[ec]);
if (ec)
{
    // An error occurred.
}
```

My library uses `std::error_code` and `std::system_error` to report errors. My question is how can I make `boost::asio::yield_context` set a `std::error_code` instead of `boost::system::error_code`? I'd like users of my library to be able to do this:

```
std::error_code ec;
auto result = remoteProdedureCall(args, yield[ec]);
if (ec)
    handleError();
```

where `remoteProcedureCall` would look something like:

```
Result remoteProcedureCall(Args args, boost::asio::yield_context yield)
{
    //...
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, argsBuffer, yield);
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_, resultBuffer, yield);
    if (invalidResult())
        // Return a std::error_code via the yield object somehow???
        // (My error codes belong to a custom error_category)
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

**P.S.** I should indicate that my library uses error codes that belong to a custom `error_category`.

Comment: I realize that what I'm asking for may be impossible, but someone may find a clever trick or hack that would do the job. Or perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way.

Comment: An idea might be to use some kind of wrapper around `boost::asio::basic_yield_context`.

Comment: I could overload `operator+(yield_context&, std::error_code&)` so that it returns a `yield_context_wrapper` that contains the original `yield_context`, plus a pointer to the user's `std::error_code` variable. I would also provide a `yield_context_wrapper` conversion constructor that takes a `yield_context`.  My API functions would then take a `yield_context_wrapper` argument instead of `yield_context`, thus gaining access to the user's `std::error_code` variable.

Answer (score 2):

I ended-up doing something much simpler than trying to coerce `yield_context` into setting an `std::error_code`:

```
// This overload sets a std::error_code if there's an error.
Result remoteProcedureCall(Args args, boost::asio::yield_context yield,
                           std::error_code& userErrorCode)
{
    //...
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    boost::async_write(socket_, buffer, yield[ec];
    if (ec)
    {
        userErrorCode = toStdErrorCode(ec);
        return Result();
    }
    // ...
    if (someNonBoostError)
    {
        userErrorCode = make_error_code(myCustomErrorCode);
        return Result();
    }
    // ...
    return result;
}

// This overload throws an exception if there's an error
Result remoteProcedureCall(Args args, boost::asio::yield_context yield)
{
    std::error_code ec;
    auto result = remoteProcedureCall(args, yield, ec);
    if (ec)
        throw std::system_error(ec);
    return result;
}
```

where `toStdErrorCode` converts from a `boost::system::error_code` to a `std::error_code`, as per Sam's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27973853/245265) (also see this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176471/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-boostsystemerror-code-to-a-stderror-code?lq=1)).

---

Even simpler would be to make `remoteProcedureCall` take an optional pointer to an `error_code`. This avoids having duplicate functions: one that sets the error code, and another that throws an exception.

Comment: The downside with this approach is that it effectively doubles the number of functions in my API.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, assuming `ec` is a `boost::system_error::error_code`

```
std::make_error_code( static_cast<std::errc::errc>(ec.value()) );
```

I believe the `boost::system::errc::errc_t` enums are mapped to the same value in [`std::errc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errc).

Comment: Thanks, but I need to go the other way around. My function wants to return a `std::error_code` via the `yield` object. My error codes (which belong to custom error categories) don't map to the ones in `std::errc`, nor to `boost::system::errc`.