# What is the difference between boost::system::error_code and boost::system::error_code::value()?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

For example, the following code compiles. Will `test1` always equal `test2`?

```
boost::system::error_code ec = foo()
bool test1 = ec.value() == boost::asio::error::would_block;
bool test2 = ec == boost::asio::error::would_block;
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

The categories will not match up. In fact it's pretty tricky to bridge the two because the categories are global singletons, but they can't be shared because of the statically different types.

*The reason Boost's types exist is because they predate standardization/vendor implementation on various platforms*.

See here for ideas on how to use shim categories to mix the two types if you **need** to pass boost::system::error_code as std::error_code:

[Is it possible to convert a boost::system::error_code to a std:error_code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176471/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-boostsystemerror-code-to-a-stderror-code/10559993#10559993)

Using `value()` is not very safe because it just drops all category information and goes back to treating errors are `int`. This may seems to work like a charm for a long time, until you encounter errors from difference categories.